# How to handle events in jQuery UI widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to write a jQuery widget following the model given [here](http://bililite.com/blog/understanding-jquery-ui-widgets-a-tutorial/).
Here is a snapshot of the widget:

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.notification", {
        _create: function () {
            if (!this.element.hasClass("ntfn")) {
                this.element.addClass("ntfn");
            }

            this.elTitle = this.element.append("<div class='ntfn-title'>Notifications</div>");

            this.elTitle.click(this._titleClick)
        },
        _titleClick: function () {
            console.log(this);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here the problem is with the scope of "this" inside the `_titleClick` method, inside the method this points to the `title` element. But I need it to point to the `widget` element.

I think one way of doing it will be to use a wrapper class like

```
var that = this;
this.elTitle.click(function() {
    that._titleClick.apply(that, arguments);
});
```

Is this the best way to solve this problem or is there any general pattern to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a method my own to solve this issue

```
_wrapCallback : function(callback) {
    var scope = this;
    return function(eventObject) {
        callback.call(scope, this, eventObject);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Use the [`this._on()` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_on) to bind the handler. This method is provided by the jQuery UI widget factory and will make sure that within the handler function, `this` always refers to the widget instance.

```js
_create: function () {
    ...
    this._on(this.elTitle, {
        click: "_titleClick" // Note: function name must be passed as a string!
    });
},
_titleClick: function (event) {
    console.log(this);       // 'this' is now the widget instance.
},
```

Comment: I didn't know about this. I think this is the best choice if you do not need to reference the element that was clicked.

Answer (score 5):

You should look to jQuery.proxy() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

```
el.bind('evenname', $.proxy(function () {
   this.isMyScope.doSomething();
}, scope));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your create, init (or somewhere in your instance) function do this:

```
        _create: function() {

        ...

        // Add events, you will notice a call to $.proxy in here. Without this, when using the 'this'
        // property in the callback we will get the object clicked, e.g the tag holding the buttons image
        // rather than this widgets class instance, the $.proxy call says, use this objects context for the the 'this'
        // pointer in the event. Makes it super easy to call methods on this widget after the call.
        $('#some_tag_reference').click($.proxy(this._myevent, this));

        ...

        },
```

Now define your objects event hander like this:

```
        _myevent: function(event) {

            // use the this ptr to access the instance of your widget
            this.options.whatever;
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

define *var scope=this*, and use *scope* in event handler.

```
    _create: function () {           
        var scope = this;
        $(".btn-toggle", this.element).click(function () {
            var panel = $(this).closest(".panel");
            $(this).toggleClass("collapsed");
            var collapsed = $(this).is(".collapsed");
            scope.showBrief(collapsed);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same thing without using closure, is to pass the widget as a part of the event data like so:

```
// using click in jQuery version 1.4.3+.
var eventData = { 'widget': this };

// this will attach a data object to the event,
// which is passed as the first param to the callback.
this.elTitle.click(eventData, this._titleClick);

// Then in your click function, you can retrieve it like so:
_titleClick: function (evt) {
    // This will still equal the element.
    console.log(this);
    // But this will be the widget instance.
    console.log(evt.data.widget);
};
```

Comment: This is what I would do when I need to be able to reference the element that was click, and also get access to the widget instance.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be via the jquery [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method now [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is favoured.

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in
>   the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call
>   to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion
>   of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

```
_create: function () {
   var that = this; 
   ...
   elTitle.on("click", function (event) {
             event.widget = that;   // dynamically assign a ref (not necessary)
             that._titleClick(event);
    });
},
_titleClick: function (event) {
    console.log(this);             // 'this' now refers to the widget instance.
    console.log(event.widget);     // so does event.widget (not necessary)
    console.log(event.target);     // the original element `elTitle`
},
```